# AngularJS ngClass conditional for multiple variable in sorting

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I am using multiple-sorting in angularjs here I want to add class on clicked Li tag, Its working fine when I am using single value sorting by code below:

```
<li ng-class="{ active:sortType === 'rollno'}"><a ng-click="sortType = 'rollno';"><span>Sort by Rollno</span></a></li>

<li ng-class="{ active: sortType === 'marks'}"><a  ng-click="sortType = 'marks';"><span>Sort by marks</span></a></li>
```

but when I use multiple-value sorting its not changing its class as expected in code below:

```
  <li ng-class="{ active:sortType === ['rollno','marks']}"><a ng-click="sortType = ['rollno','marks'];"><span>Sort by Rollno</span></a></li>

<li ng-class="{ active: sortType === ['marks','rollno']}"><a  ng-click="sortType = ['marks','rollno'];"><span>Sort by marks</span></a></li>
```

My sorting is working fine but issue in changing a class on sorted li tag.
In controller:

```
$scope.sortType='';
```

Comment: Just like you would in Javascript: `{ active:sortType === 'rollno' || 'marks'}`

Comment: no sir by using your its putting both li tag active, but I want sort by Roll no active on-{ active:sortType === ['rollno','marks']} and sort by marks active on-{ active: sortType === ['marks','rollno']}.
I hope its clear to you.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is not equal to another array in JavaScript, even if both contain the same strings:

```
console.log(['a'] === ['a']); // prints false
```

So you need another way to know if the sort type is `['rollno','marks']` or `['marks','rollno']`.

You could simply use

```
ng-class="{ active: sortType[0] === 'rollno' }"
```

Or you could add a function to your controller like

```
$scope.isSortTypeEqualTo = function(sortType) {
    return angular.equals($scope.sortType, sortType);
};
```

and use

```
ng-class="{ active: isSortTypeEqualTo(['rollno','marks']) }"
```

Comment: just before your answer I did the same and got expected result.
Thanks a lot for this appropriate answer. :) :)

Comment: @Arunchauhan Will you please do me a favor. Please tell me only my answer is correct or not ?

Comment: I have Posted the answer below what I am using in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf()` to test whether a value is in an array and then use it inside your `data-ng-class` like

```
<li data-ng-class="{ 'active' : (sortType.indexOf('rollno') == 0)}"><a ng-click="sortType = ['rollno','marks'];"><span>Sort by Rollno</span></a></li>

<li data-ng-class="{ 'active' : (sortType.indexOf('marks') == 0)}"><a  ng-click="sortType = ['marks','rollno'];"><span>Sort by marks</span></a></li>
```

On the first check, you will get `rollno` at 0th index and in another one you will get `marks` at 0th index.

I am assuming that you're defining `sortType` as an array in controller first. Please check a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dg8o1Ly5/).

Comment: Both will always be active. Your code is basically equivalent to `data-ng-class="{ 'active' : true}"`

Comment: Okay, will you please tell me then why OP is assigning both values in an array at same time `ng-click="sortType = ['rollno','marks'];"` ?

Comment: Because he wants to sort by rollno, then by marks. I.e. once sorted by rollno, the items having the same rollno would be sorted by marks.

Comment: What I got its all about to add a class. Isn't it ?

Comment: The OP wants to make the first li active if the sortType is equal to `['rollno','marks']`, and the second one active if the sortType is equal to `['marks','rollno']`. Your answer doesn't do that at all. It just passes a very complex boolean axpression, that is **always true**, whatever the value of sortType is. Read my answer.

Comment: @JBNizet, Thanks for your clarification. I will be back within a minute. Thanks :-)

Comment: @JBNizet sir, Will you please check my edited answer and let me know if I am still doing it in wrong way ?

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks sir. Its enough for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of my problem, but posting this answer to help other in the same aspect:-

we can simply use

ng-class="{ active: sortType[0] === 'rollno' }" in case of sort by Rollno

`<a ng-click="sortType = ['rollno','marks'];"><span>Sort by Rollno</span></a>` 
and same for ng-class="{ active: sortType[0] === 'marks' }" in case of sort by marks

```
<a  ng-click="sortType = ['marks','rollno'];"><span>Sort by marks</span></a>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Assign rollno or marks to onclick function then the code will work.
You need to change your code as follows to work..

```
<li ng-class="{ active:(sortType =='rollno'|| sortType =='marks')}"><a ng-click="sortType ='rollno'"><span>Sort by Rollno</span></a></li>

<li ng-class="{  active:(sortType =='rollno'|| sortType =='marks')}"><a  ng-click="sortType ='marks'"><span>Sort by marks</span></a></li>
```